# Does dehydrate activity in bpel synchronous process return fault or error?

Tags: bpel

Does dehydrate activity in BPEL synchronous process return fault or error?

version used: Oracle 12.2.1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Vinay,**

I think dehydration merely leads to storage of the instance to a server. Therefore depending on the situation, a dehydration may follow a fault or instance, but it cannot lead to them. In your case, I assume the dehydration happens in the middle of the synchronous process, so the instance is effectively removed from the stack. This will return a fault from your source, or generate a fault in your composite, depending on where the instance faulted. I would recommend looking in the enterprise manager, or other tooling you use to manage flow traces, to see where the process goes wrong.

The following links contain nice descriptions of the dehydration process:

[Dehydration in BPEL - Oracle SOA Suite 11g](http://www.soatutor.com/2012/08/dehydration-in-bpel-oracle-soa-suite-11g.html)

[Understand the dehydration process in SOA BPEL](https://chendamok.wordpress.com/understand-the-dehydration-process-in-soa-bpel/)

I hope I understood your question correctly, have a nice day! :)

Jesper